# some troubles in running react-native app on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, deployment, build

I have some troubles in running the app on IOS
using this command react-native run-ios

after some solutions and much googling , it finally ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

however - the simulator opens but not launch the application

> ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
>
> The following commands produced analyzer issues: Analyze
> /Users/mohsen/Desktop/MrTanWork/app-dev/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetInfo.m
> normal x86_64
>
> (1 command with analyzer issues)
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app.app
>
> Launching org.reactjs.native.example.app
>
> org.reactjs.native.example.app: 17154

what else should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried building it through Xcode?

Comment: @Andrew , Yes it was making different issues - Mapbox module not found

Comment: Is that error still happening? There may be a issue with the linking of mapbox

Comment: @Andrew , it succeeded inside XCode now , but it fires this message : Unable to boot device due to insufficient system resources.

Comment: Sounds like your development machine is doing too much.

Comment: @Andrew - it returned to the previous error : mapbox is not found ,, it looks like noway

Comment: You should look over the linking of mapbox with ios and make sure that you have implemented it correctly

Comment: One other thought are you opening the `appname.xcworkspace`